# Dynamic container view swift programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on an application that's supposed to create some modules dynamically and I'm struggling in making a view that can hold as many containers as needed without them overlaying each other. is there a way to create a variable number of container views that will not overlay?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `UITableView` with multiple expected layout types as cells and dynamically according to the response array configure it, you can also use `UIStackView` embedded inside a `UIScrollView` for a simple structure